# Error---only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy

```
movie_user_likes ="Avatar"

movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie_user_likes)


similar_movies = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[movie_index]))
sorted_similar_movies = sorted(similar_movies,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)


i=0
for movie in sorted_similar_movies:
     print (get_title_from_index(movie[0]))
     i=i+1;
     if i>50:
       break
```

I am getting an error that

> error---only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis
>   (`None`) and integer or
>         boolean arrays are valid indices

I have cosine values of the points that I am trying to sort:

> [[1. 0.10540926 0.12038585 ... 0. 0. 0. ]
>   [0.10540926 1. 0.0761387 ... 0.03651484 0. 0. ]
>    [0.12038585 0.0761387 1. ... 0. 0.11145564 0. ] ]

Comment: You should provide more details about your datatypes, what were you expecting to achieve?

Comment: i have cosine values of the points that i am trying to sort

Comment: [[1.         0.10540926 0.12038585 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.10540926 1.         0.0761387  ... 0.03651484 0.         0.        ]
 [0.12038585 0.0761387  1.         ... 0.         0.11145564 0.        ]